# What's the convergence of this summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^{i-1}=a^0+a^1+a^2+...+a^{n-1}=1+a+a^2+...+a^{n-1}$$

Looks like a geometric series. Is there a more compact formula for the convergence of this summation?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a^{i-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^{i}=\frac{1-a^n}{1-a}$$
and thus it converge for $|a|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a geometric series (with ratio $a$)! Check out WolframAlpha's page on them: [Geometric Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html). It gives the derivation that you're after (not really much point my copying it - it's all in the link). Note, though, a comparison of notation: "your $a$" = "their $r$", "your $i$" = "their $k$ and "their $a_k$ = your $a^i = a^k$". Should be pretty clear from the page. :)

Another point to note is that this converges if and only if $|a| < 1$. We see that for $|a| > 1$, the terms increase in magnitude, so certainly no convergence. For $a = 1$, it is just the sum of lots of $1$s - clearly not convergent. Slightly more delicately, when $a = -1$, the sum alternates between $1$ and $0$, but never settles down, so doesn't converge.

Hopefully this helps! Remember to upvote if it does! ;) haha! =)

Comment: Also, see the Wikipedia page here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series.